# how replace select2 default spinner?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-select2

**How replace the [select2](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2) spinner.gif?**

I have tried with the next css:

```
.select2-container-multi .select2-choices .select2-search-field input.select2-active {
   background: #fff url('custom-spinner.gif') no-repeat 100% !important;
   background: #fff url('custom-spinner.gif') no-repeat 100% !important;
 }
```

This is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I don't achieve replace the default `select2-spinner.gif` with `spinner1-gif`

This is the css https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/blob/master/select2.css

Comment: FYI, it's already been renamed in 3.3.1.

Comment: What's not working, exactly? Your code might work, but it's hard to say anything without seeing your situation.

Comment: if the css dose not refer anymore to the default spinner. How it come u still have it??unless it's caching issue

Comment: This rule are correct? I have the last version of select2 plugin. Can you paste a correct css for replace the spinner?

Comment: It depends on what version you're using ("latest" doesn't help--latest stable? latest dev?), but you'd just search for the image name in select2.css and change the path there, or you'd copy those styles and change it in a separate stylesheet. We can't very well give you specifics without knowing what your version and file path are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's every instance of 'spinner.gif' in select2.css, version 3.3.1. Copy this, change each instance of the file path, and place it in a stylesheet that loads *after* select2.css.

```
.select2-search input.select2-active {
    background: #fff url('select2-spinner.gif') no-repeat 100%;
    background: url('select2-spinner.gif') no-repeat 100%, -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.85, white), color-stop(0.99, #eeeeee));
    background: url('select2-spinner.gif') no-repeat 100%, -webkit-linear-gradient(center bottom, white 85%, #eeeeee 99%);
    background: url('select2-spinner.gif') no-repeat 100%, -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, white 85%, #eeeeee 99%);
    background: url('select2-spinner.gif') no-repeat 100%, -o-linear-gradient(bottom, white 85%, #eeeeee 99%);
    background: url('select2-spinner.gif') no-repeat 100%, -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 85%, #eeeeee 99%);
    background: url('select2-spinner.gif') no-repeat 100%, linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 85%, #eeeeee 99%);
}

.select2-more-results.select2-active {
    background: #f4f4f4 url('select2-spinner.gif') no-repeat 100%;
}

.select2-container-multi .select2-choices .select2-search-field input.select2-active {
    background: #fff url('select2-spinner.gif') no-repeat 100% !important;
}
```